# Как построить полигон по кадастровым координатам

Tags: c#, алгоритм, winforms

Есть координаты полигона взятые из кадастровой палаты

```
    x           y
443177,62   1350151,5
443155,59   1350158,35
443150,45   1350137,1
443174,01   1350131,3
443177,62   1350151,5
```

Как их перевести в обычный формат, чтобы построить полигон на canvas? Никак в голову не приходит как их начертить

Comment: Что такое "обычный формат"?

Comment: ну координаты которые помещались бы в canvas. А то тут в сотни тысячах координаты за пределы формы выходят

Comment: умножайте на коэффициент который соответствует canvas
если вам дано 1000000 а максимум это только 100, то и умножайте 1000000 на 0.00001

Comment: если совсем по умному делать, то читайте про матричные преобразования

Comment: лучше метку алгоритм добавьте а также уточните о какой канвасе идет речь. Могу только wpf предположить

Answer (score 1):

Если цель - рисовать карту, то лучше взять готовые компоненты.
Для них можно указать систему координат, и тогда не придётся ничего умножать.
dotSpatial или Gdal позволяют создать полигон по точкам, а нижеуказанные компоненты уже этот полигон нарисуют.

Бесплатные - SharpMap, MapWindow, MapAround